How can I set up Google Sheets to automatically copy and name a template tab daily?
Is there a way I can set up Google Sheets to automatically copy and name a tab on a daily or weekly basis?

Welcome to [webapps.se].  Please take the [Tour] and see [ask]. You may wish to search this site for similar questions using the tag [tag:google-apps-script] or read about the copyTo(spreadsheet) method in Google's Apps Script documentation.

There is a similar question Is there a way to add a new sheet tab to a Google Sheet based on the timestamp date?  and answer which you might find helpful in answering this question.

Also, it would be helpful if you could provide more details about what criteria or input you are using to determine when Google Sheets should create a new tab. In this question the input was the timestamp on a Google form. What are you using to determine when a new tab should be created in Google Sheets?
